Possible limitation of PlaneDetectionProvider on VisionOS
When using the plane PlaneDetectionProvider in visionOS I seem to have hit a limitation which is that regardless of where the headset is the space, planes will only be detected that are (as far as I can tell) less that 5m from the world origin.
Mapping a room becomes very tricky as a result because you often find some walls are outside the radius, even if you're standing three feet away from a ten foot wall. It just won't see it. I've picked my way through the documentation but I cannot see any way to extend this  distance. Am I missing something?

It turned out that ARKit wan't updating new planes after the initial setup. I replaced the entire setup and it snapped back into life.
